# Auto publish my joomla articles in my facebook page

Tags: facebook, joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5

I have a [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Produits-et-Service-Allemand-au-Maroc/663313843689725) and i want to **publish** my joomla website **articles** in this page, that mean after add a new article in my website automatically published in the facebook page, [here is my web site](http://www.import-produit-allemand.com/), so plz if someone has any ***idea*** i will be very appreciative :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-share/social-multi-share/18072 comes with auto publish to Facebook and Twitter. I'm using it on my site and it has an auto Facebook page import function in the plugin parameters itself. It has all the configuration options you need.

Comment: [Joomla Social Submit](http://foobla.com/joomla/obsocialsubmit) by foobla does the job out-of-box. Check it out http://foobla.com/joomla/obsocialsubmit

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of developed plugins and components which will do the job. Check the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-share/social-auto-publish), you will see, that there are commercial and non-commercial solutions that might fit your needs.